# Redis : How to back up redis data from remote to local?

Tags: database, redis, backup

I have local redis in my ubuntu and remote redis that I am using with aws.
I wonder is there any way I can save up data from remote connection in my local ubuntu.

Comment: Did you set up the remote or is it managed (i.e. ElastiCache)?

Comment: @ItamarHaber it is managed by ElastiCache

Comment: I believe they have just made backup available - look at their blog post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. run `SLAVEOF host port` at your local redis
2. run `BGSAVE` to dump to disk